# In a web extension background script, how to know if webNavigation.onCompleted is for a tab itself and not a subframe or ajax?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am migrating my extension from Firefox to Chrome and in Firefox following code determined if the page just being loaded, is a main tab and not a frame or ajax inside one nor a new opened fresh tab:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(navCompleted)
function navCompleted(o) {
    if (o.frameId!=0) return
    //rest of code
}
```

But in Chrome a fresh new tab has frameId different from 0! And working with `parentFrameId == -1` is not working either because new tabs have a parentFrameId 0!
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what happens without seeing the actual `o`. In my test I see a new tab's frameId is `0` and the url is `chrome://new-tab-page/`

Comment: My point is that the thing you described doesn't happen here and I've never seen it happen in Chrome.

Comment: ?? Are you sure? I'll paste some screenshots when I'm on my laptop later.

Comment: That's what my comment says.

Comment: I can already say now that a new tab on my logs has chrome://about (or similar) and frameId 2286. Why is it different with you?

Comment: So far it sounds like it's a very very old Chrome that used a frame inside the default start page. Indeed, in those times we had to use chrome.tabs.get to read the real URL of the tab which was chrome://newtab.

Comment: So your first comment is from a very very old Chrome??

Comment: No, it's the opposite: your description makes sense only if you use the very old Chrome. All my comments refer to the modern Chrome.

Comment: Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I also added picture in original post

Comment: Interesting. So this different to the old Chrome (meaning we can forget about my guess), but this is still not how Chrome behaves by default, meaning there must be a reason like maybe you've customized or changed the home/start page.

Comment: I crawled a bit deeper and I did find the same as you (`url: "chrome://newtab/"`) but not on `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted`, but on `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`. Maybe that where you were looking? Although no frameId there. Strange..
Anyway, I think I am gonna migrate to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` even though it means more `if`s in my listener. Since I think the other is buggy or bad supported.

Comment: I've tested chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted. I know how it works and I've been using it for 5+ years.

Comment: The only explanation left is that you have an extension that overrides the newtab page and that page contains an about:blank iframe. You can use `chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted` which will work in this case correctly. The fact that `onCompleted` doesn't fire for frameId `0` means there's a bug in Chrome, which is not surprising as there are hundreds of bugs in the extensions API which no one fixes for years.

Comment: Thanks in any case.
P.S. It is strange that about:blank and newtab ARE different in my chrome, although I don't have any extensions that SHOULD do that. (Besides openeing the one instead of the other) But, other extensions  IS a use case, so yeah...bug or not, I got to go around.